# How to up a specific migration (e.g. m151125_053608) in YII 1.1

Tags: php, yii, database-migration, yii-migrations

Is it possible to migrate up a specific migration in Yii 1.1 ?

I have created some migrations but i want to execute a specific migration before all other migrations are up.

Also, `yiic migrate up 3` will migrate the latest three migrations and at the same time when i used `yiic migrate up 1` , it doesn't asking for the intended migration.

I have tried `yiic migrate up m151125_053608` but it is not working.

How to achieve such scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already create three migrations and want to add new one to be first. Then just create file name matching that RegExp `/^(m(\d{6}_\d{6})_.*?)\.php$/`.

Something like this: `m150101_000000_100.php`

But all next migrations shoudn't be applied yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two ways to make this:

1. Run the command:

```bash
yiic migrate to 151125_053608 # In this case
```

2. By modifing the migration info (if the migration to apply is the last)

**Important:** copy the timestamp to restaurate the migration info later.

```bash
yiic migrate mark ######_###### Timestamp of the penultimate migration
```

After this do

```bash
yii migrate
```

Apply migration and restore the migration information with the timestamp copied.

Ref: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration